# How can I make the list of largest abscissae from a nested list of coordinates?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, numerics, sorting, table

Suppose I have a nested list of coordinates as:

```
list = {{{0.318252, 0.000182017}}, {{0.275664, 0.0962279}, {0.275664, 
    0.0962272}, {0.317855, 0.00142638}}, {{0.275661, 
    0.0962363}, {0.317442, 0.00271887}}, {{0.275662, 
    0.0962445}, {0.275664, 0.096242}, {0.31703, 
    0.00400394}}, {{0.275649, 0.0962696}, {0.27566, 
    0.096259}, {0.316615, 0.00529192}}, {{0.275634, 
    0.0963016}, {0.275664, 0.0962705}, {0.316201, 
    0.00657358}}, {{0.275651, 0.0963029}, {0.315791, 
    0.00784293}}, {{0.275671, 0.0963051}, {0.315375, 0.00912365}}}
```

How do I select only the greatest abscissae out of the above nested list to get the answer as the following?

```
{0.318252, 0.317855, 0.317442, 0.31703, 0.316615, 0.316201, 0.315791, 0.315375}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 list = {{{0.318252, 0.000182017}}, {{0.275664, 0.0962279}, {0.275664, 
    0.0962272}, {0.317855, 0.00142638}}, {{0.275661, 
    0.0962363}, {0.317442, 0.00271887}}, {{0.275662, 
    0.0962445}, {0.275664, 0.096242}, {0.31703, 
    0.00400394}}, {{0.275649, 0.0962696}, {0.27566, 
    0.096259}, {0.316615, 0.00529192}}, {{0.275634, 
    0.0963016}, {0.275664, 0.0962705}, {0.316201, 
    0.00657358}}, {{0.275651, 0.0963029}, {0.315791, 
    0.00784293}}, {{0.275671, 0.0963051}, {0.315375, 0.00912365}}}

First @* First @* MaximalBy[First] /@ list
```

{0.318252, 0.317855, 0.317442, 0.31703, 0.316615, 0.316201, 0.315791,
0.315375}

Or

```
Map[MaximalBy @ First, list][[All, 1, 1]]
```

{0.318252, 0.317855, 0.317442, 0.31703, 0.316615, 0.316201, 0.315791, 0.315375}

**In this particular case** we get the same result with

```
Max /@ list
```

{0.318252, 0.317855, 0.317442, 0.31703, 0.316615, 0.316201, 0.315791, 0.315375}

Answer (score 5):

**Using `RankedMax`:**

```
list = {{{0.318252, 0.000182017}}, {{0.275664, 0.0962279}, {0.275664, 
    0.0962272}, {0.317855, 0.00142638}}, {{0.275661, 
    0.0962363}, {0.317442, 0.00271887}}, {{0.275662, 
    0.0962445}, {0.275664, 0.096242}, {0.31703, 
    0.00400394}}, {{0.275649, 0.0962696}, {0.27566, 
    0.096259}, {0.316615, 0.00529192}}, {{0.275634, 
    0.0963016}, {0.275664, 0.0962705}, {0.316201, 
    0.00657358}}, {{0.275651, 0.0963029}, {0.315791, 
    0.00784293}}, {{0.275671, 0.0963051}, {0.315375, 0.00912365}}}

RankedMax[#[[All, 1]], 1] & /@ list
```

> {0.318252, 0.317855, 0.317442, 0.31703, 0.316615, 0.316201, 0.315791,
>
> 0.315375}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{{0.318252, 0.000182017}}, {{0.275664, 0.0962279}, {0.275664, 
     0.0962272}, {0.317855, 0.00142638}}, {{0.275661, 
     0.0962363}, {0.317442, 0.00271887}}, {{0.275662, 
     0.0962445}, {0.275664, 0.096242}, {0.31703, 
     0.00400394}}, {{0.275649, 0.0962696}, {0.27566, 
     0.096259}, {0.316615, 0.00529192}}, {{0.275634, 
     0.0963016}, {0.275664, 0.0962705}, {0.316201, 
     0.00657358}}, {{0.275651, 0.0963029}, {0.315791, 
     0.00784293}}, {{0.275671, 0.0963051}, {0.315375, 0.00912365}}};

ReverseSortBy[#, First][[1, 1]] & /@ list
  (* {0.318252, 0.317855, 0.317442, 0.31703, 0.316615, 0.316201, 0.315791, 0.315375} *)

TakeLargestBy[#, #[[1]] &, 1][[1, 1]] & /@ list
  (* {0.318252, 0.317855, 0.317442, 0.31703, 0.316615, 0.316201, 0.315791, 0.315375} *)

Sort[#, #1[[1]] > #2[[1]] &][[1, 1]] & /@ list
  (* {0.318252, 0.317855, 0.317442, 0.31703, 0.316615, 0.316201, 0.315791, 0.315375} *)
```